# Game Engine Runtime Decompression

Tags: c++, compression

I have been trying to find out how game engines deal with asset compression. Obviously they compress all the assets when building the game. But how do they decompress them during runtime. The only thing I could think of was decompressing into memory, but that must be very memory intensive. If they decompressed onto the HDD a folder would be filling up while the game is playing? This doesn't sound very efficient.

Using a library like zlib (or any other) with c++,  how is this runtime decompression done?

David

Comment: I don't know what 'asset' means here specifically, but if you have a lot of separate compressed files, you might try decompressing on demand + some caching. So a file is decompressed in memory only when it's needed, and then it's cached, and if it's not needed for a time is discarded from the cache when other files need to be decompressed, to prevent the cache from becoming too big.

Comment: by asset I mean files needed for the game, things like images, meshes, materials, shaders that sort of thing

Comment: In "Game Coding Complete" there was pretty much the method satuon described.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's kinda like this, you have a game with so much data that it won't fit in a reasonable amount of memory, so you can't load all of them at once in memory, so you define some buffers for the data that you use as caches.

Now memory in order of speed from lowest to highest is as such:

- DVD
- Hard Drive
- RAM

Ideally you won't have to stream data from the DVD, but it's something to take into account if you have to make a console game for instance. So for each of these available storage spaces you define a buffer to be used as a cache.

When the game engine decides that it might need an asset, it should first look in the fastest cache to see if the asset is already loaded. If it is then you're in luck, you can immediately send it to be drawn. If it's not in the fastest cache, you have to go down a level to the hard drive cache. This is a file where you keep assets that were already decompressed and ready to be loaded into memory. If the fastest cache isn't fully occupied then you can just start loading the data and use it when it's ready. If there isn't enough space, then you will have to unload other assets first, I would recommend removing the least recently used assets until you have enough space to load the new one.

Now if the hard drive cache doesn't have the data loaded then you have to go down one more level to the archive, you will want to use the zip format to compress it because the zip file format doesn't force you to decompress the entire archive to have access to just one file so all you have to do is find the offset of said file within the archive and decompress it into the hard drive cache. Again if the cache is full you'd have to unload some other assets first, again I'd recommend removing the least recently used but you can try other algorithms as well if you think it will improve performance.

John Karmack had a keynote at QuakeCon 2011 where he explained this whole process maybe a little bit better than I can in a post (among other awesome things), you can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zgYG-_ha28)

Answer (score 3):

Compression can happen in many ways on many different layers, and when, where and how its used are totally dependent what its aims & goals are (compression isn't always about saving space on disk).

Very basically, on a top level, all assets would/could be compressed into a bulk archive (this speeds up reads, as there is less to read from the HDD, but you are sacrificing processing power for this, as apposed to using DMA to read uncompressed files, which doesn't use the CPU at all), read back is almost always done memory to memory, reading back to the HDD would destroy performance and cause a host of problems (and in some cases would be impossible, such as on older generation consoles).

A second tier can/could be done on the asset itself, as an example, textures can be compressed in MANY different ways, but mainly block compression (S3TC/DXTn, BCn) is used these days as its decompression is supported in hardware (or emulated by the driver), so when once its read for the archive/disk, no further decompression needs to be done.

The compression strategies also vary per platform, especially on consoles which are very sensitive to memory layout, have limited resources and have small caches etc.

> Using a library like zlib (or any other) with c++, how is this runtime decompression done?

generally you want to use memory mapped files of the archive and decompress directly to RAM, a good example of a AAA archive system that is well documented that does this is the [MPQ format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPQ) (used by Blizzard Entertainment, more details [here](http://www.zezula.net/en/mpq/mpqformat.html)), it uses a variety of compression algos, such as deflate for Diablo I, zlib for Warcraft III, bzip2 in World of Warcraft, and they recently added LZ and sparse compression for their newer games like SCII.

Jan Wassenberg' thesis (`Optimizing File Accesses via Ordering and Caching`) has a good breakdown of file management, that may also be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

> game engines deal with asset compression

There are different game engine assets such as geometry models (triangulation/ polygonal model), textures, etc. Each asset class has a different compression strategy. Can you be more specific ?

For model compression, [Check this](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/dissertation.pdf)

Comment: Ok lets say textures. the reason I say this is because the engines I have worked with previously appear to compress nearly everything into a one or two files that they use at runtime

Comment: I think you should see this : http://www.webpronews.com/google-talks-texture-compression-for-games-at-gdc-2012-03